# Cloudant - partly update document - http api

Tags: couchdb, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I have a need to partly update a document in a cloudant db. The reason is that I want to create a doc, add a image (attachment) to that doc and send the img url to an external image processor. Later I want to update the doc in cloundant with the result of the image processing. I'm doing this from swift/mobile and don't want to copy the file more than once. There seems to be no way to partly update a doc, according to the api doc. But maybe someone has found a way to do this. I see that I can copy docs, but assume that will give me the same isse when I need to add some info to the doc. Maybe it's possible to copy and merge?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to query Cloudant for the doc (all of the JSON), add or update the key/value pair of the field in question, and then save the doc (or, `PUT` the doc) to the database.

Make sure that when you save the doc, you include the latest _rev value.

More here:
http://docs.cloudant.com/document.html#update

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about updating docs independently of attachments, this is not only possible, but recommended.

First [`PUT` the document](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/document/common.html?highlight=doc#put--db-docid), then [`PUT` the attachment](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/document/attachments.html?highlight=doc#put--db-docid-attname) (with the appropriate `rev` query parameter). Afterwards, you can update the document independently from the attachment.

To update the document (without updating the attachment), you should [`GET` the document](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/document/common.html?highlight=doc#get--db-docid), and note that it includes an "attachment stub". As long as you preserve the stub when you [`PUT` a new version of the document](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/document/common.html?highlight=doc#updating-an-existing-document), the attachment will be preserved. Example of a document with an attachment stub:

```
{
  "_id":"attachment_doc",
  "_rev":1589456116,
  "_attachments":
  {
    "foo.txt":
    {
      "stub":true,
      "content_type":"text\/plain",
      "length":29
    }
  }
}
```

Answering your more general question about partial updates, you can use [update functions](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/ddocs.html?highlight=document%20update#update-functions), but they are more cumbersome when working with attachments.

Comment: Tanx - I see how.. I have some issues with alamofire and complex JSON's but I guess I find a way to preserve the stub...

Comment: do I need to keep it _attachments - if I do I cant add anything else to the doc...

Comment: Yes, you do need to keep the `_attachments`. Why can't you add anything else to the doc?